# Google earth GEOdata?

Tags: geolocation, geometry, geospatial, google-earth, google-earth-plugin

Question: Is it possible to use/retrieve Geodata from Google-Earth ?

What I want to do is take a little area, get terrain information (coordinates, height, elevation) and simulate how the selected area would be flooded at specified amounts of rain for a specified amount of hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Free terrain data for specified areas [can be retrieved](http://srtm.csi.cgiar.org/SELECTION/inputCoord.asp) from NASA's SRTM mission, which used radar mapping from the space shuttle. I think Google Earth uses this same data.